# Getting a span to disappear when hovered over another div

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to have the `#please` span disappear whenever `.btn--alt` is hovered. Right now, when I hover it becomes a mess. Should I have the email address stacked underneath the original div to stop it from jumping?

https://jsfiddle.net/0m5w268f/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function excute when mouse pointer **enters** the element, so your order of argument is wrong.

This should work:

```
 $(".btn--alt").hover(
    function () {
        $("#please").fadeOut();
    },
    function () {
        $("#please").fadeIn();
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0m5w268f/3/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the functionality you are looking for but try reversing the JQuery hover stuff to be.

```
$(".btn--alt").hover(
        function () {
            $("#please").fadeOut();
        },
        function () {
            $("#please").fadeIn();
        }
    );
```

This is due to the HandlerIn being the first part and the HandlerOut being the second part.

> Calling
>
> $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
>
> is shorthand for:
>
> $( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );

Source: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

You have the fade backwards

```
 $(".btn--alt").hover(
        function () {
            $("#please").fadeOut();
        },
        function () {
            $("#please").fadeIn();
        }
    );
```

See this example:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pm7dqk5r/)